# What's the appropriate toast after successful CRUD operation?

Tags: toast

Assume we have a website or mobile app, that has e.g. a list of messages. User can add/delete/edit a message. After making an operation user receives a toast that operation has succeeded.

What's the most appropriate toast message for this scenario?

1. `<entity>` **was** `<action>`
2. `<entity>` **has been** `<action>`
3. `<entity>` `<action>`
4. `<action>`
5. Something else

For example, if the `<entity>` is a "message" and performed `<action>` was "adding to favorites", the toast could say "`Message` **has been** `added to favorites`". I wonder if there's the conventional way of saying this according to some UI guides. Or I am just being meticulous.

Comment: "`<action>`, **was the** `<entity>`" is clearly the best choice.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Sure, if you're designing an interface for Yoda.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus ["There is no `<entity>`"](http://danielmurakami.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/there-is-no-spoon.jpg).

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Wouldn't that be `<action>, the <entity> was`?

Comment: @hobbs I usually use bread to make toast, but to each his own.

Comment: Only toast *if the toast does not interfere with the UI*. Users may dislike waiting 5 seconds for a ***Trivial Success!!!*** message to disappear before they can do anything else.

Comment: A similar question (a little more specific) is here: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/11651/what-is-the-right-success-message/11652

Answer (score 50):

I lean *strongly* toward concision in communication. Which you choose depends on the rest of your UI.

Without further context, I would suggest option 3, which is the approach we take in our own style guide: simply *"Message added to favourites"*. It provides adequate reinforcement that they completed the *desired action* on *the expected entity*.

Adding "was", "has been" does not serve to increase understanding and arguably only adds (albeit marginally in most people) to cognitive load in parsing extra words in the sentence. As someone with a language processing disability myself, I've always found that type of verbiage an unnecessary nuisance.

Comment: Good point about the extra wording being a possible hindrance. I hadn't considered that aspect.

Comment: @maxathousand Thanks. I'm _extra_ sensitive to it having an LD. Some people find it reinforcing, but I do not. It's why I share it as a personal experience rather than an absolute. It really needs to go in context of the rest of the UI and what the users expect: are they philosophers or software engineers?

Comment: And this brevity (provided it doesn't lead to ambiguity) seems especially important in a toast message where space is often limited.

Comment: If only `messages` can be added to `favorites`, I think just `Added to favorites` would be sufficient. Thoughts?

Comment: @Traxo Definitely. But that's not the case here as OP specifically mentions they have a variable `<entity>`. If only one type of entity can be acted upon, then the entity name can be dropped. _Unless_ there is value in reinforcing the entity (say, two work contexts look similar and you want to ensure the user understands that they have changed something specific).

Comment: > `If only one type of entity can be acted upon, then the entity name can be dropped.` Ok, in OP's case `list of messages` on mobile - `message` would probably be the only resource that can be `added to favorites` on current screen. Perhaps if you agreed with me you could update the answer. I think there is value in your additional points.

Answer (score 15):

I respectfully disagree with the other answers.  `Foo barred` parses ambiguously in English: does it mean that the foo *was* barred or that the foo *did* the barring?  How many possible meanings does `settings user deleted` have?  At least some of the time, writing that tersely will lead to confusion, or crash blossoms,  and once you rewrite one case to remove the ambiguity, all your other messages will now be inconsistent.  And in a particularly misleading way: if you went out of your way to say that the foo *was* barred, wouldn’t you have done that to `Baz meeped` if you meant the baz *was* meeped, not doing the meeping?

Comment: Shoot, you're right. Now I'm doubting my reversal of stance... I guess for this very reason is why I tend to favor slightly more verbose, but unambiguous wording.

Comment: @maxathousand:  Sometimes you have to choose between brevity and precision.  The correct choice depends on your audience.  Communication should be optimized to your audience.  When your target audience is "most people" the correct choice is brevity.  (While `Foo barred` is ambiguous, the people most likely to find it ambigous are people who can handle ambiguity.)

Comment: @maxathousand I click "Edit" to edit a user.  I edit.  I click "Save."  A toast appears saying "User saved."  Given the context of what just happened, it should be clear I was doing the saving, not the user.

Comment: Sure, but other situations might be more ambiguous. Imagine a slow connection (where actions and responses could be some time apart), a distracted user (where responses are not observed immediately), or entities that also control aspects of the application. To illustrate the last example, I'm currently working on software that controls machinery. There are real-world entities that the user configures, known as "Equipment Controls". If a user sees "Equipment Control updated", they might not know if the *equipment control* just changed something (which is possible), or if it *was* changed.

Comment: @WordsLikeJared In that case (see previous comment), a user could misinterpret a message, even in context.

Comment: @WordsLikeJared Are you sure *you* aren’t the user who saved? I find it hard to understand how a copula would be more confusing than the ambiguity.

Comment: @maxathousand Case 1 - all toasts are the result of user actions: well the user perfomed the action, so it's clear they caused it. Case 2 - some toasts are not the result of user actions - well maybe always speak in active voice.  So "You updated Equipment Control" and "Equipment Control updated X" could be the toasts.  Also see my next comment.

Comment: Respectfully, "foo barred" and "settings user deleted" are _extremely_ contrived examples. The phrase OP would have to use is "User settings deleted" (with 'user settings' the entity and 'deleted' the action) _in response to clicking the delete button on someone's user settings._ That is not ambiguous. With your example, adding words doesn't help parsing: "settings user have been deleted" is no more intelligible, nor is "foo was barred".

Comment: @Davislor: 

I'll answer as if you were my fellow coworker: My original comment was more about a general principle than answering in this case.  In this case I don't think it's a big deal either way.  I don't feel strongly enough to argue for it.  There are more profitable uses of my time.  Next steps, I'd say:  pick a standard (any standard) and change it later once we have some better information - maybe talk to end users or take some surveys or ask an expert or something.

Comment: If "<entity> was/has been <action>" is suspected to add to cognitive load, but just "<entity> <action>" may be ambiguous, how about "<entity> is <action>". That's simple, always true and unambiguous.

Comment: @ChristiaanWesterbeek Wouldn’t *is* add just as much cognitive load as *was*?  Is there any study that supports the notion that reading the word *was* causes more cognitive load than a double meaning? Or that this is a significant problem? Even the person who suggested it does wrote complete, grammatically-correct sentences that used auxiliary verbs.

Comment: @msanford *Noun verbed* is literally the exact grammatical construction at issue here, and `Foo was barred` completely resolves whether *foo* is the subject or the object of the transitive verb *barred*. Phrasing like “User updated” becomes “contrived” and confusing the moment we lack context to tell whether something updated the user or the user updated something, or maybe it’s specifying that the user who updated or was updated is the one we mean. Just substitute a different noun and verb for which we don’t have that context, and you yourself say it’s a confusing message.

Comment: @msanford However, you are correct that `settings user deleted` would only occur as a phrase inside a longer sentence. It was the first example that came to mind of a phrase where the *-ed* suffix could mean several different things, and probably not the best.

Comment: @msanford To resolve `settings user deleted` by adding words: `settings that the user deleted`, `the settings user deleted it`, `the settings user was deleted`,  `settings have been user-deleted`, etc. Or you would change the word order and add punctuation to get something equally short and avoid the ambiguity, because the ambiguity is confusing.

Comment: I disagree with this, because the context will make it clear what is meant. You just gave a command to bar a foo, so "foo barred" merely confirms that it did what you told it to do. E.g. if you're in a mail program and click on "Delete Message", only an idiot would think that "Message Deleted" means that the message performed the deletion (and if so, what did it delete?).

Comment: @Barmar Won’t there sometimes be messages that aren’t the direct, expected result of your actions? The original argument against *was* or *has been* was originally that more words meant more “cognitive load” and made the sentences more difficult to understand. If the user should just figure out what an ambiguous message means from context, then what is the advantage of terseness?

Comment: @Davislor There may be, but it sounds like an exception, and we don't need to design general responses that way. In most cases the meaning will be obvious -- in fact, you could just say "Done" and the user would understand.

Comment: @Barmar `Done` sounds like a fine solution to those cases. Why is this a reason to prefer `Foo barred` to `Foo has been barred`, though?

Comment: It just seems needlessly wordy for a simple acknowledgement message. Especially if it causes the message to overflow to a second line.

Comment: But that wasn't my complaint. I was not objecting to that as a preference, but as being necessary to ensure the message is understood.

Comment: What entity should "settings user" be? "Settings user was/has been deleted" isn't in any way better, its still an absolutely poor toast.

Comment: The "settings user" example was a contrived one meant to illustrate how the ungrammatically-terse phrase could parse in many different ways. And therefore did not really have lower "cognitive load." The actual toast would probably be, "Deleted the settings user," but I'd been challenged to disambiguate by adding words only.

Comment: I don't disagree that there's *rarely* going to be an actual problem here. Although it's hard for the person writing the toasts to foresee what other ways people are going to interpret it. They have the full context that the user might not.

Answer (score 13):

5. None.

Giving a toast every time an `<action>` has been *successfully* performed, is annoying and wasteful of the user's time.

Instead of a toast on *success*, if there is a *failure* to perform the `<action>`, present a useful error message and/or provide corrective steps such as reopening the `<entity>` for editing.

This is the least disruptive method to lead to the user correcting errors on their part, or let them know that there is a service issue.

The UI should be responsive enough, say, having a list of the `<entity>` to be changed, the `<action>`  should be obvious to have been performed or not.

Comment: A toast is not "an error" so I don't understand where you're going with that line of reasoning.  As far as "responsiveness" goes, if the action causes something to vanish from the list, it may not be immediately obvious whether that's because it got deleted, or moved to a different list, or something else entirely.  Worse, in a very long list, individual items appearing or disappearing may be hard to see.

Comment: Indeed. When users expect application to work reliably, they don't need constant assurance that the application didn't fail. Conversely, if you constantly announce success, you may give impression that it can't be trusted and needs to be verified. Compare experience of plugging in a USB mouse into a Mac (complete silence) with connecting a Bluetooth one (there is a popup indicator). That's because USB one is expected to always work, and Bluetooth is famous for being flaky.

Comment: I agree completely. If the user's intent was to cause the <entity> to undergo some <action> and the result was exactly that, then all they need is a big green tick.
You can give more detailed feedback if other things have occurred. I've seen a toxic version of this where a modal alert was used thereby adding half a second to every operation for no reason.

Comment: I don't completely agree with this answer. While it's true that these messages shouldn't be abused, feedback is still extremely important. It may be possible to skip displaying a toast, if, say, a message is deleted, because with the aid of an animation, the effect is pretty obvious to the user. On the other hand, a send confirmation toast could be appropriate imo, although mail clients like Apple's will play a sound as feedback. In op's case, "added to favourites" could be shown with a heart or a similar glyph on the item.

But in every case, there is *some kind* of feedback.

Comment: I would argue that toast notifications are only needed when it is _non-obvious_ from looking at the UI that an action has succeeded. In the context of the basic CRUD actions referred to by the original question, it should be very obvious whether those actions have succeeded or not. Therefore I don't see the point of toast notifications in this scenario. I agree 100% with this answer.

Comment: Kevin: Editing to make that section a bit more clear.

Answer (score 5):

<sub><sup><preamble></sup></sub> One of the most important goals of your UI should be to allow the user to perform what they want with as little friction as possible. Effective feedback is a key aspect of this. The UI should be as transparent as possible, clearly showing the user how to perform tasks, what the user is about to do, and what the user has done. <sub><sup></preamble></sup></sub>

Taking these points into consideration, I'd posit that "`<entity>` **has been** `<action>`" or "`<entity>` **was** `<action>`" should be the template for your feedback. Informing the user *which* entity was acted upon as well as *what* was done will aid in processing your feedback without requiring the user to recall any information on their own. This is especially useful if your user is on a slow connection and actions may be completed after some time.

Deciding between these two tenses ("was" versus "has been") for your response would be a good question to search for or post over at [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: And yet there are many programs out there that simply say _potrzebie added to widget_.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I'm sorry, I don't understand the point you're raising in this comment. Would you expand?

Comment: I don't necessarily disagree with your suggestion that **has been** or **was** is a good way of handling it; however, it seems not to be the default - virtually every program that I've seen out there that uses similar messages omits the 'to be' verb in favor of the short form <object> <verb-phrase-past-tense> - e.g., _potrzebie added to widget_.